# Accessing another server's file system passing credentials

Tags: windows, network-share, credentials

I'm trying to access the file system on a server (\\servername), which prompts for credentials.
I want to pass the credentials directly, like \\username:password@servername, but it's not working.

An example:
\\"FirstName LastName":"myp@ssword"@servername doesn't work. Notice the white space in the user name and the @ in the password. I want to support this.

Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're on a windows machine, your syntax is all wrong.

```
C:\Users\me>net use  /?
The syntax of this command is:

NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]
```

See how that differs from what you're trying?  The username needs to be preceded by the `/user:` switch with a single slash, not a double-backslash.

Comment: I'm not trying to map anything to a drive, I'm trying to access a server's file system (\\servername) by supplying the credentials directly in that. But thank you for the reply.

Comment: The method you are using can work with HTTP but I've never seen it work with CIFS, maybe you are accessing a Web Folder (DAV)? You could do this with a Linux box using the **smbclient** utility but I am not aware of a way to do it via UNCs alone in Windows. Maybe try runas?

Comment: @Dante - mfinni is still correct even without a mapped drive.  `Net Use \\server\share /user:DOMAIN\user password` is the command.  Then any subsequent connections in Explorer, etc. to that share will use those credentials (even more so with the /SAVECRED).  It's not mapping a drive, just creating the connection to the UNC path

Comment: @TheCleaner is correct. You don't have to map a drive, but you do have to establish credentials with the UNC path.

Comment: I thought I had seen it but you are right, it was in an url. Thank you  for all replies!